# select duplicates from two columns by row and create a new variable in R

Tags: r, duplicates, data-mining

I have a data frame in which I have different duplicates of ID and dates. I just want to detect the duplicates of one column that are also in the other so I can say: 
1. remove the rows with duplicate id, duplicate datee and missing in T (second record in this table). 
2. And then say: if there is a duplicate id and duplicate date, chose the T=="high".

```
id<-c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c")
datee<-c("12/02/10", "12/02/10", "12/02/10","10/03/11", "10/04/18","1/04/18" )
T<-c("high", NA, "low","high", "low", "medium")
mydata<-data.frame(id, datee, T)
```

This is like this:

```
id    datee    T
a 12/02/10    high
a 12/02/10 <NA>
a 12/02/10    low
a 10/03/11    high
b 10/04/18    low
c 1/04/18     medium
```

Comment: Possibly something like this `mydata_ord <- mydata[order(mydata$id, mydata$datee, as.character(mydata$T)),];
first <- !duplicated(mydata_ord[, c("id","datee")]);
mydata_ord[first,]` but it would be more helpful if you posted what the desired output looked like

Comment: Also it's generally a good idea to avoid naming an object or element of an object `T` since in Rstudio this is an alias for `TRUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A step by step solution

Step 1 - Remove missing

```
mydata<-mydata[!is.na(mydata[,3]),]
```

Step 2 - Identify duplicated rows on ID

```
dup_rows_ID<-duplicated(mydata[,c(1)],fromLast = TRUE) | duplicated(mydata[,c(1)],fromLast = FALSE)
mydata_dup<-mydata[dup_rows_ID,]
```

Step 3 - Identity duplicated rows on ID  and datee

```
dup_rows_ID_datee<-duplicated(mydata_dup[,c(1,2)],fromLast = TRUE) | duplicated(mydata_dup[,c(1,2)],fromLast = FALSE)
```

Step 4 - Select T="high"

```
mydata_dup2<-mydata_dup[mydata_dup[dup_rows_ID_datee,"T"]=="high",]
```

Your output

```
rbind(mydata_dup[rownames(mydata_dup) %in% rownames(mydata_dup2),],
+  mydata[!dup_rows_ID,])
  id    datee      T
1  a 12/02/10   high
4  a 10/03/11   high
5  b 10/04/18    low
6  c  1/04/18 medium
```

About ID==a you have two date with T=="high", you have to choose if you want the one with higher or lower datee.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this first:

```
is_duplicate <- lapply(X = mydata, FUN = duplicated, incomparables = FALSE)
is_na <- lapply(X = mydata, FUN = is.na)
```

and use data.frames to f.ex. remove the rows with duplicate id, duplicate datee and missing in T like this:

```
drop_idx <- which(is_duplicate$id & is_duplicate$datee & is_na$T)
data[drop_idx, ]
```